# Can pocketsphinx_continuous read from stdin?

Tags: stdin, speech-recognition

There is one parameter -adcdev "Name of audio device to use for input.", but it doesn't say if this can be stdin. Can pocketsphinx_continuous read from stdin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in version 0.8, you can use `-infile` as in `pocketsphinx_continuous -infile /dev/stdin`. The documentation is still trying to catch up with this new feature!